# Перевод математических формул в с++

Tags: c++

Ребята, подскажите пожалуйста где допустил ошибку и логику того как правильно и почему так правильно. спасибо

определил, что решил неправильно с помощью проверочной суммы, где переменная x=4, y=7, результат=1.3893

[image: стартовое уравнение]

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    double x;
    cout << "Enter x=";
    cin >> x;

    double y;
    cout << "Enter y=";
    cin >> y;

    double result = sin((x / 2) + 3 * y) + cos(2.3 - sqrt(x*y));

    cout << "result:" << result << endl;

    system("Pause");
}
```

Comment: https://bit.ly/2KYVXTW Там и есть такой результат

Comment: а как Вы проверяли? на калькуляторе в windows?

Comment: Что у вас за компилятор такой, что он у вас пропустил такой код? Gcc ругается на две ошибки, первая это не определена функция `sqrt`, исправляется это подключением `#include <cmath>`.  Второе, это у вас `void main() `, а должно быть `int main() `

Comment: sin(23) + cos(2.3 - sqrt(28)) == -1.83498

Comment: Вероятно вы проверяли там, где тригонометрические функции считаются в градусах. В этом случае результат примерно 1.38937. В с++ же они принимают углы в радианах, и это выражение даёт -1.83498.

Comment: @B1aZe visual c++. Но это не является стандартом и линуксовые компиляторы такое не кушают.

Answer (score -1):

`#include <math.h>` и `#include <cmath>`
Библиотеки забыли.

Answer (score -2):

```
double result = sin(((double)(x / 2)) + 3 * y) + cos(2.3 - sqrt(x*y));
```